Split MPI AlltoAllV into smaller segments
Suppose every rank's send buffer is made up of smaller, not necessarily full subarrays of equal type
rank 0:
|DDDDDDD____|DDDDD______|DDDDDDDDDD_|DDDDDDD____|...
^ send.begin()
 (to rank0)  (to rank1)  (to rank2)  (to rank3)

rank 1:
|DDDDD______|DDDD_______|DDDDD______|DDD________|...
^ send.begin()
 (to rank0)  (to rank1)  (to rank2)  (to rank3)

...

to be communicated with MPI_Alltoallv. Despite extensive measures, sometimes send's size will exceed the range addressable with 32-bit signed integers, making it necessary to split data into multiple segments. What are the idioms of MPI 3.1 to deal with such situations?
Since send is a contiguous buffer, incrementing the begin pointer does not help to shield the too large offset of size_t from MPI. MPI derived data types are sometimes recommended for large data transfers (sending data: MPI_Type_contiguous vs primitive types), but how would these work with Alltoallv?

Pick a MPI library that implements MPI standard 4.0 or above, and use MPI_Alltoallv_c()

That seems to be the most elegant solution, but I am forced to stay with version three of the standard. Are there any alternatives?

If applicable, use intermediate vectors. For example instead of sending 2^32 elements, declare a vector of 1024 elements and send 2^22 vectors.
